# cookienotice.js?ver=1:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null en aviso de coockie

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

dispongo de un archivo para el aviso de coockie que contiene el siguiente codigo:

```
function accepted() {
setCookie('CookieHinweis', true, 1);
document.getElementById("cookie-info").style.display = "none";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
}
return "";
}

// Set to the same value as the web property used on the site
var gaProperty = 'GOOGLE KEY';
// Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
window[disableStr] = true;
}

// Opt-out function
function gaOptout() {
document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 
UTC; path=/';
window[disableStr] = true;
alert('Das Tracking durch Google Analytics wurde in Ihrem Browser für diese 
Website deaktiviert.');
}

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
}

gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'GOOGLE KEY', {'anonymize_ip': true});

$("#gaOptoutLink").click(function () {
   gaOptout()
});

if (!getCookie('CookieHinweis')) {
    document.getElementById("cookie-info").style.display = "block";
}
```

el archivo esta preparado para implementar Google Analytics, de hecho no es la primera vez que lo uso y esa funcional en varias web´s.

Luego dispongo tal que asi el contenedor html

```
<div id="cookie-info" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', 
     238)); ?>
    <button id="accept-cookie" class="button" 
    onclick="accepted()">Einverstanden</button>
</div>
```

Como veis, recibo se imprime un mensaje llamado desde un post en mi cms

El problema es que en este projecto, de repente, estoy recibiendo el siguiente fallo:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at cookienotice.js?ver=1:58

Y me indica que la linea que falla es:

```
if (!getCookie('CookieHinweis')) {
    document.getElementById("cookie-info").style.display = "block";
}
```

Y la verdad es que no encuentro el problema, alguien me podria ayudar? Gracias

Comment: Intenta cambiar el orden (html antes y js despues), parece que tu js se ejecuta antes de cargar el `div`.

Comment: Nop, lo he intentado, pero sigue dando el mismo fallo

Comment: Por alguna razon cuando tu JS se ejecuta el DOM aun no esta completo y no encuentra el div. Si puedes usar JQuery introduce la parte que falla en un `.ready()` o si quieres usar solo JS puro -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: Intenta debuggearlo con google chrome. y pararlo en ese momento, y mira que te devuelve document.getElementById("cookie-info").

Comment: @JDev El tema de js puro, el document ready, te sirve si el elemento está pintado con el resto, si por algún casual lo añades con js después no tiene por que estar "ready" cuando lo este el DOM. Es una buena opción, pero para que tenga en cuenta que si lo añade con js después puede seguir fallandole.